# Chrome app for Worldbuilding

Tags: discussion

So I've made a chrome app ([see a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93WIn.jpg)) that simply opens the web browser to the Worldbuilding SE. Since I have homepage set to chrome://apps/ and I visit WB frequently, I thought this would be pretty cool to have so I made it originally for myself. I figured someone might want this so here is the [download link](http://www.filedropper.com/worldbuilding) for it. Here are the steps to install it:

1. Download and unzip the folder.
2. Open Chrome.
3. Go to chrome://extensions. Check the box that says Developer Mode.
4. Click Load Unpacked Extension...
5. Select your file (make sure it is unzipped!).
6. Reload the page and go to chrome://apps, and it should be there!

Sorry if this isn't a question, didn't really know where to post it. 
Also, the icon is the worldbuilding icon for the iOS app.

Comment: I don't typically use Chrome. But thanks for sharing. And you're right, meta is a good place to share such information.